# My function for deleting the first node in a linked list delete the 2nd node instead

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
 /* Node structure */
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;
```

This is my node structure

```
   
 /* Create the linked list */
void create_list(Node *head) {
    char check;
    int i=1, num;
    char * temp;
    
    printf("Input data for node 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    head->data = num;
    
    printf("\nEnter more <y>es/<n>o ? ");
    scanf(" %c", &check);
    
    while(check=='y') {
        head -> next = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        head = head->next;
    
        printf("\nInput data for node %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &head->data);
        i++;
        head->next = NULL;
        printf("\nEnter more <y>es/<n>o ? ");
        if (scanf(" %c", &check)!= 1) {
            printf(" Error: Invalid Input \n");
            scanf(" %s", &temp); /* Clear input buffer */
            continue;   
    }
}
}
```

This is the function to create the linked list

```
/* Delete first location*/
void delete_first(Node *head) {
    Node *prev_node;

    prev_node = head;//assign the prev pointer to beginning of the list
    head = head->next;//shift the node to next
    
    if(head == NULL)//condition for no elements in list
        printf("\n The List is empty ");
    else { //logic for deletion
        prev_node->next = head->next;
        free(head); //delete the node
}
}
```

This is the function to delete the first node

```
int main() {
Node *head, start;
    
start.next = NULL;
head = &start;
    
create_list(head);

head = &start;
delete_first(head);
}
```

This is my main

This is my code. Like the title the function to delete the first node turn out to delete the 2nd node instead. I think it has something to do with my create list function but atm I can't figure out why.

Comment: How do you know it is deleting the second node? Please provide the code or method you are using to determine that. But one thing that stands out is that `delete_first` is not returning the new head to the calling function. Note that `head` is a local variable inside the function and changing it does not change the caller's variable.

Comment: `head = head->next; ... free(head);` Why are you moving to `next` before deleting the node? Don't you want to delete `head` as that is the first node? But one aspect of the design may cause you problem - head is static memory whereas all other nodes are dynamic memory. Better to make everything dynamic memory.

Comment: In the whole program I have a function to display all the node as well, so when I run the program I see the 2nd node got deleted instead of the first

Comment: If the duplicate question list is not helpful, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `delete_first` is changing the value of what `head` points to, but has no way of conveying that back to the caller. Remember, passing the pointer `head` enables the caller to change the contents of head, but upon return, `head` is still pointing to what it was originally - which is a deleted node.

I see a few other bugs, so let's clean this up.  It's far simpler than you have it.  We can either have `delete_first` return the new "head" as a return value, or as an "out" parameter by allowing the caller to pass a pointer to a pointer.  Let's go with the latter in this example:

```
void delete_first(Node **ptrToHead) {

    Node* head = *ptrToHead;

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        *ptrToHead = head->next;
        free(head);
    }

}
```

But your `create_list` function has a similar bug. So let's fix that, but we'll use return style signature so it's easier to read

```
Node* create_node(int value)
{
    Node* n = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = value;
    return n;
}

Node* create_list() {
    char check;
    int i=1, num;
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node* last = NULL;
    
    printf("Input data for node 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    head = create_node(num);
    last = head;
    
    printf("\nEnter more <y>es/<n>o ? ");
    scanf(" %c", &check);
    
    while(check=='y') {
    
        printf("\nInput data for node %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &num);
        i++;

        last->next = create_node(num);
        last = last->next;

        printf("\nEnter more <y>es/<n>o ? ");
        if (scanf(" %c", &check)!= 1) {
            printf(" Error: Invalid Input \n");
            scanf(" %s", &temp); /* Clear input buffer */
            continue;   
    }

    return head;
}
```

Then main becomes this:

```
int main() {
    Node *head = create_list();
    
    // delete the first node - this will update "head"
    delete_first(&head);

    return 0;
}
```